# Why all the contents in a scrollview are not being shown?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview

Below is my XML file .I have put all the contents inside a ScrollView Inside a Linear Layout , and as you can see , another layout which is containing all the views is wrapped inside the ScrollView but my last button widget is not visible on running. What could be the possible reason and solution for the same?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Overview"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Program Structure"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Tokens , Semicolons and Comments"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Data Types"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:text="Variables"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:text="Constants and Literals"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:text="Operators"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:text="Decision Making"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:text="Loops"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:text="Functions"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:text="Scope Rules"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:text="Arrays"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Pointers"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:text="Strings"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn15"
            android:text="Structures"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn16"
            android:text="Typedef"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn17"
            android:text="Input and Output"/>
        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn18"
        android:text="File I/O"/>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn19"
        android:text="Preprocessors"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn20"
            android:text="Header Files"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn21"
            android:text="Type Casting"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn22"
            android:text="Error Handling"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn23"
            android:text="Recursion"/>



    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Only the last? Is it completely invisible?

Comment: just put **android:fillViewport="true"** in your scrollView

Answer (score 0):

Replace your xml file with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/bar_chart_main_scroll"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Overview"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Program Structure"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Tokens , Semicolons and Comments"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Data Types"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:text="Variables"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:text="Constants and Literals"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:text="Operators"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:text="Decision Making"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:text="Loops"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:text="Functions"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:text="Scope Rules"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:text="Arrays"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Pointers"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:text="Strings"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn15"
            android:text="Structures"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn16"
            android:text="Typedef"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn17"
            android:text="Input and Output"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn18"
            android:text="File I/O"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn19"
            android:text="Preprocessors"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn20"
            android:text="Header Files"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn21"
            android:text="Type Casting"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn22"
            android:text="Error Handling"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/btn23"
            android:text="Recursion"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hope this works for you. Do let me know if it works or if you require further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NestedScrollView as show below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

............ (Your other Views)        

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**android:isScrollContainer="true"** This is important.

Hope it works. Any doubt, just comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of setting margins, scrollview sometimes ignore them. Check instead of first button top margin and last button top margin, remove those two margins and replace those two margins with views with same height. That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:fillViewport="true"
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Overview"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Program Structure"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Tokens , Semicolons and Comments"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Data Types"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:text="Variables"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:text="Constants and Literals"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:text="Operators"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:text="Decision Making"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:text="Loops"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn10"
        android:text="Functions"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn11"
        android:text="Scope Rules"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn12"
        android:text="Arrays"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:id="@+id/btn13"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Pointers"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn14"
        android:text="Strings"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn15"
        android:text="Structures"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn16"
        android:text="Typedef"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn17"
        android:text="Input and Output"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn18"
        android:text="File I/O"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn19"
        android:text="Preprocessors"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn20"
        android:text="Header Files"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn21"
        android:text="Type Casting"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn22"
        android:text="Error Handling"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/btn23"
        android:text="Recursion"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

I just added the attribute "fillViewPort = "true"" to the XML. 
You can see in the docs that when you use the "fillViewPort" the scrollView stretch as much as possible to make the view Visible to the user.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView